# Function 'DisplayArray' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting a error and because of this my code wont work. The error is "Function 'DisplayArray' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used". I can't get rid of this error. I'm new to programming, can anyone help?

```
Private Function DisplayArray() As String
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    ReDim Preserve Array(UpperSub)
    Dim AddNum As Double = 0.0
    txtAddNum.Focus()
    If Double.TryParse(txtAddNum.Text, AddNum) Then
        If AddNum > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Number must be below 100")
        ElseIf AddNum < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Number must be above 0")
        Else
            Array(UpperSub) = CDec(AddNum)
            UpperSub = UpperSub + 1
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Value has to be a number")
    End If
    txtAddNum.Clear()
    txtDisplay.Clear()
    For j = 0 To UpperSub - 1
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text _
          & CStr(Array(j)) & ControlChars.NewLine
    Next
    txtNumberOfScores.Text = CStr(UpperSub)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Function` is designed to **return** a result, using the `Return` keyword.  Your Function does not have a `Return` statement.  Since none of the possible code paths (determined by branching on the `If` statements as well as the flow from beginning to end) return a value, you're getting this part of the error message: "Function 'DisplayArray' doesn't return a value on all code paths."

The second part of the error message means that if you tried to assign the return value of the `Function` to a variable, like this:

```
Dim result As String = DisplayArray()
```

You'd get a null value, as nothing is returned from the function.

The simplest solution is to change from a `Function` to a `Sub`.  `Sub`s in VB.NET do not return a value.  So change

```
Private Function DisplayArray() As String
```

To

```
Private Sub DisplayArray()
```

And

```
End Function
```

To

```
End Sub
```

Note that the `As String()` in the `Function` declaration says this method will return a value that is a `String`, and the `Sub` has no return value (again, because it doesn't return a value).

To make this a `Function` that returns a value, you'll have to return at least one value from the method.  Here's an example:

```
Private Function DisplayArray() As String

    Dim j As Integer = 0
    ReDim Preserve Array(UpperSub)
    Dim AddNum As Double = 0.0
    txtAddNum.Focus()

    If Double.TryParse(txtAddNum.Text, AddNum) Then
        If AddNum > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Number must be below 100")
            Return String.Empty
        ElseIf AddNum < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Number must be above 0")
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Array(UpperSub) = CDec(AddNum)
            UpperSub = UpperSub + 1
            txtAddNum.Clear()
            txtDisplay.Clear()
            For j = 0 To UpperSub - 1
                txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text _
                    & CStr(Array(j)) & ControlChars.NewLine
            Next
            Return CStr(UpperSub)                
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Value has to be a number")
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Essentially, if the validation fails, an empty string is returned.  If the validation passes, the rest of the code is executed and the string value of `UpperSub` is returned.

You could then assign it to the `TextBox` like this:

```
txtNumberOfScores.Text = DisplayArray()
```

The above is a *simple* example based on your posted code, intended to show you how to return values from a `Function`.  Adjust it to fit your needs (or use a `Sub` instead).  Given that you want to update the display of the `txtDisplay` with the array and `txtNumberOfScores` as well you should do fine with a `Sub`.